# Should [cep] and [complex-event-processing] be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

It looks like [cep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep) and [complex-event-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complex-event-processing) should be merged.  Their tag wikis are similar and there are some overlapping questions.  Wikipedia confirms this similarity as well.

Comment: I feel almost like they're both lacking , so not sure which tag will be subsumed :\

Comment: If they are indeed the similar, then it would be better to synonymize them (and make [complex-event-processing] the master tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with acronyms is that we can never be sure that all the posts are related to the same full form. We never know if CEP stands for "Close Every Post!". I went through all the 507 questions to check if they were all related to Complex Event Processing. There were some unclear ones like [how to display data which received from another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238371/how-to-display-data-which-received-from-another-server)  which I just closed and deleted.

Luckily enough, all the questions were related to Complex Event Processing. I merged the tags, [complex-event-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complex-event-processing) and [cep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep) and also added a synonym: [complex-event-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complex-event-processing) ← [cep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep)